# How to check if a div has an svg in it using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I have a div like the following with a question mark in it...

```
<div id="mydiv">?</div>
```

In my code, when someone tries to submit a form, I do a check to see if that field has a question mark in it, like this:

```
const fieldText = $('#mydiv').text();
return fieldText.indexOf('?') !== -1;
```

That works fine, but now, instead of a question mark in that div, I have an SVG of a question mark (rather than just a text question mark), like this.

```
<div id="mydiv">
  <svg version='1.1' id='Layer_1' class='q-mark-svg' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' x='0px' y='0px' viewBox='0 0 50 50' style='enable-background:new 0 0 50 50;' xml:space='preserve'>
    <style type='text/css'>
      .q-mark{fill:#777777;}
    </style>
    <g>
      <g>
        <path class='q-mark' d='M18.3,17.2c0,0.4-0.1,0.7-0.2,1c-0.1,0.3-0.3,0.6-0.5,0.8c-0.2,0.2-0.5,0.4-0.8,0.5c-0.3,0.1-0.6,0.2-1,0.2 c-0.7,0-1.3-0.2-1.8-0.7c-0.5-0.5-0.7-1.1-0.7-1.8c0-1.6,0.3-3.2,0.9-4.6c0.6-1.4,1.5-2.7,2.6-3.8s2.3-1.9,3.8-2.5 c1.4-0.6,3-0.9,4.6-0.9s3.1,0.3,4.6,1c1.4,0.6,2.7,1.5,3.8,2.6s1.9,2.3,2.6,3.8c0.6,1.4,0.9,2.9,0.9,4.5c0,3.2-1.2,6-3.5,8.4 l-3.8,3.5c-1.3,1.3-2,2.7-2,4.3c0,0.7-0.2,1.3-0.7,1.8c-0.5,0.5-1.1,0.7-1.8,0.7s-1.3-0.2-1.8-0.7c-0.5-0.5-0.7-1.1-0.7-1.8 c0-2.9,1.2-5.6,3.5-7.9l3.8-3.6c1.3-1.4,2-2.9,2-4.8c0-0.9-0.2-1.8-0.5-2.6c-0.4-0.8-0.8-1.5-1.5-2.1c-0.6-0.6-1.3-1.1-2.1-1.5 c-0.8-0.4-1.7-0.5-2.6-0.5c-0.9,0-1.8,0.2-2.6,0.5c-0.8,0.4-1.5,0.8-2.1,1.4c-0.6,0.6-1.1,1.3-1.4,2.1 C18.5,15.3,18.3,16.2,18.3,17.2z M28.5,40.9c0,1-0.3,1.8-1,2.5c-0.7,0.7-1.5,1-2.5,1c-1,0-1.8-0.3-2.5-1c-0.7-0.7-1-1.5-1-2.5 c0-1,0.3-1.8,1-2.5c0.7-0.7,1.5-1,2.5-1c1,0,1.8,0.3,2.5,1C28.2,39.1,28.5,40,28.5,40.9z'/>
      </g>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

I still want to run a check on that div, but now I have to check to see if it has an SVG in it, rather than just "?".  How can I use JS to check if a div has an svg element in it?

FYI, I tried the following since I thought it would still look for the text, but to no avail...

```
const fieldText = $('#mydiv').text();
return fieldText.indexOf('svg') !== -1;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

jQuery is overkill here. You can use vanilla javascript and `getElementsByTagName` to return an array of matching elements **inside specific elements**. Then you can test against the length of the returned array (0 serving as false in the condition).

**For example** Two tests, one with svg in a div, and one without:

```js
var t1 = document.getElementById('test1');
var t2 = document.getElementById('test2');

// Used in a simple conditional statement
if (t1.getElementsByTagName('svg').length) {
  console.log('test1 has svg');
}
if (t2.getElementsByTagName('svg').length) {
  console.log('test2 has svg');
}
```

```html
<div id='test1'></div>
<div id='test2'><svg></svg></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this out `$('#mydiv').find('svg').length)`

If `svg` exists then you will get length as some value, if not then value will be 0.

Hopw this will help you.

Comment: Doesn't this also match svg in the text body instead of the tags?

Comment: @Jesin Going through text will be more text matching than the `HTML` tags

Comment: Never mind, it turns out `find` is a jQuery method that does what is needed here, though more slowly than `querySelector`.

Answer (score 2):

Find `svg` tag inside div.

```js
if($("#mydiv").find("svg").length) {
   alert("I found SVG");
} else {
    alert("SVG is not found");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="mydiv">
   <svg version='1.1' id='Layer_1' class='q-mark-svg' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' x='0px' y='0px'
  viewBox='0 0 50 50' style='enable-background:new 0 0 50 50;' xml:space='preserve'>
  <style type='text/css'>
     .q-mark{fill:#777777;}
  </style>
  <g>
     <g>
        <path class='q-mark' d='M18.3,17.2c0,0.4-0.1,0.7-0.2,1c-0.1,0.3-0.3,0.6-0.5,0.8c-0.2,0.2-0.5,0.4-0.8,0.5c-0.3,0.1-0.6,0.2-1,0.2
           c-0.7,0-1.3-0.2-1.8-0.7c-0.5-0.5-0.7-1.1-0.7-1.8c0-1.6,0.3-3.2,0.9-4.6c0.6-1.4,1.5-2.7,2.6-3.8s2.3-1.9,3.8-2.5
           c1.4-0.6,3-0.9,4.6-0.9s3.1,0.3,4.6,1c1.4,0.6,2.7,1.5,3.8,2.6s1.9,2.3,2.6,3.8c0.6,1.4,0.9,2.9,0.9,4.5c0,3.2-1.2,6-3.5,8.4
           l-3.8,3.5c-1.3,1.3-2,2.7-2,4.3c0,0.7-0.2,1.3-0.7,1.8c-0.5,0.5-1.1,0.7-1.8,0.7s-1.3-0.2-1.8-0.7c-0.5-0.5-0.7-1.1-0.7-1.8
           c0-2.9,1.2-5.6,3.5-7.9l3.8-3.6c1.3-1.4,2-2.9,2-4.8c0-0.9-0.2-1.8-0.5-2.6c-0.4-0.8-0.8-1.5-1.5-2.1c-0.6-0.6-1.3-1.1-2.1-1.5
           c-0.8-0.4-1.7-0.5-2.6-0.5c-0.9,0-1.8,0.2-2.6,0.5c-0.8,0.4-1.5,0.8-2.1,1.4c-0.6,0.6-1.1,1.3-1.4,2.1
           C18.5,15.3,18.3,16.2,18.3,17.2z M28.5,40.9c0,1-0.3,1.8-1,2.5c-0.7,0.7-1.5,1-2.5,1c-1,0-1.8-0.3-2.5-1c-0.7-0.7-1-1.5-1-2.5
           c0-1,0.3-1.8,1-2.5c0.7-0.7,1.5-1,2.5-1c1,0,1.8,0.3,2.5,1C28.2,39.1,28.5,40,28.5,40.9z'/>
     </g>
  </g>
   </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't this also match svg in the text body instead of the tags?

Comment: My downvote was a mistake. StackOverflow will not let me change my vote until you make a small edit, like changing "Find" to "Find an" at the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this :

```
if($("svg")[0]){
    console.log("present");
} else { 
    console.log("absent");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use
`document.querySelector("#mydiv svg") !== null`
or
`document.querySelector("#mydiv svg").querySelector("svg") !== null`